# How do I use the INDEX or OFFSET functions in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-workspace, google-sheets, formulas

I have my spreadsheet set up as follows: first 10 columns full of descriptive data followed by 24 columns of month data (2 columns per month).

The last 24 columns are static and the values are updated manually.  I may add columns between the first 10 columns as needed.

So one of the columns in the first 10 is called `Current Price` and each month section also has one column called `Price`.

What I want to do is have the `Current Price` column updated automatically depending on the current date.

I created a named range and have this formula `=COLUMN(VendorsByMonth)+(MONTH(NOW())-1)*2+1` to get the index of the `Price` column of the current month.

But I'm not sure how to apply the INDEX or OFFSET functions to get and set the cell value.

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is this:

`INDEX(RANGE,ROW,COL)`

For example:

`INDEX(B2:K4,1,5)` the range has three rows (From 2 to 4).  The `1` is row 1 within the range which is row 2 of the whole spreadsheet.  The `5` is column 5 within the range which corresponds to Column F (the 6th column of the spreadsheet).